# IB Designables failed to update auto layout status

Tags: ios, swift

Whenever I set a class as @IBDesignable I get the following error and it won't pre-render the view.

[image]

I tried changing my Runpath Search Path settings as it was recommended in a similar post but to no effect.

[image]

The thing is that I'm not aware of the nature of the error and Xcode isn't helping.

Cheers.

Comment: its Xcode bug...you have to wait for update

Comment: Do u set it correctly? I mean in the UIView that u try to render? check in Identity Inspector-> Custom class -> class: Your CustomUIView with IBDesignable, Module: Your project name.

Comment: I have the same problem ,you solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Remove "IB_DESIGNABLE"(Objective-C) from your code, and only use "IBInspectable" for xib, then it works OK. Or only waiting for xcode's updating.